# How to efficiently extract a value from HiveContext Query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am running a query through my `HiveContext`

Query:

```
val hiveQuery = s"SELECT post_domain, post_country, post_geo_city, post_geo_region
    FROM   $database.$table
    WHERE  year=$year and month=$month and day=$day and hour=$hour and event_event_id='$uniqueIdentifier'"


val hiveQueryObj:DataFrame = hiveContext.sql(hiveQuery)
```

Originally, I was extracting each value from the column with:

```
hiveQueryObj.select(column).collectAsList().get(0).get(0).toString
```

However, I was told to avoid this because it makes too many connections to Hive. I am pretty new to this area so I'm not sure how to extract the column values efficiently. How can I perform the same logic in a more efficient way?

I plan to implement this in my code

```
val arr = Array("post_domain", "post_country", "post_geo_city", "post_geo_region")

arr.foreach(column => {
    // expected Map
    val ex = expected.get(column).get
    val actual = hiveQueryObj.select(column).collectAsList().get(0).get(0).toString
    assert(actual.equals(ex))
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal here?  Why do you think you need to "extract" the value onto the driver, instead of just using it within your spark queries?

Comment: Are you running these queries in a loop?  The concern is probably that you run a new query for each record you want to extract, rather than a single query that gets all of them.

Comment: @puhlen I updated my question to be more specific. Good question thanks!